# Confusing result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these queries:

```
String sql = "update time_tracker set logout = ?, totaltime = DATEDIFF(second, login, logout) from Time_Tracker where userid= ? AND CONVERT(Date, LOGIN) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())";
```

And

```
select DATEDIFF(second, login, logout) as timeDiff 
from Time_Tracker 
where CONVERT(Date, LOGIN) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
```

When I run the first query and do a `select * from table` I get the below output.

[image]

But when I run the second query it turns out to be

[image]

This is quite confusing, please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: you are setting `logout` in the `update` and using it again to set the `totaltime`. where is this other `logout` for difference coming from? does the table already have a value for `logout` and if so, what is that value?

Comment: Hi @vkp, sorry, my bad. This is a JDBC program and the `logout` is captured from a button click, and this is what that is populated in the screenshot (the logout in my first screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the query is incorrect:

```
set logout = ?, totaltime = DATEDIFF(second, login, logout)
```

This is setting the `logout` to the new value from the param, but setting the `totaltime` equal to the difference in seconds between the `login` and the previously-existing `logout` value.  Which is why you're seeing only `394`, because the previous `logout` value must have been `2016-08-25 20:23:28.000`.

To remedy this, you should pass in the same `?` param to the `DATEDIFF()` function:

```
set logout = ?, totaltime = DATEDIFF(second, login, ?)
```